# How to define DataFrame using case and match?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create Spark DataFrame `df` in one of two possible ways:

```
val dataSourceType = "option1"

dataSourceType.map{
    case "option1" => {
        val df = gu
          .retrieveFromElastic(spark, source_field)
    }
    case "option1" => {
        val df = gu
          .retrieveFromCSV(spark, source_field)
    }
}

// some operations on "df"
```

The problem is that `df` is not visible outside of `case` statement. What is the correct way to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just some minor syntax changes and you should get it like this.

```
val df = dataSourceType match {
    case "option1" => gu.retrieveFromElastic(spark, source_field)
    case "option2" => gu.retrieveFromCSV(spark, source_field)
}
```

Good luck :-)